# Android Error when clicked on Custom Suggestion

Tags: android, android-intent

I've implemented custom suggestions in my Android App through Search Dialog and I fetch my suggestions from a remote location. Following is what my searchable.xml look like:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" 
android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.ebore.TestApp.TestProvider"
android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
>
```

The problem is when I click on any suggestion shown by Search Dialog I get the bellow error in LogCat:

```
02-07 19:34:16.459: E/InputQueue-JNI(1861): channel '414a0b28 PopupWindow:416ab7b8 (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
```

I redirected to my SearchableActivity normally but **the Intent has no Extras or mMap is null** in it which should be there as according to android documentation if table/cursor includes `SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA` column the data will be received in intent under `EXTRA_DATA_KEY`.

Please help I am badly stuck here.